# Flutter detect swipe left and right click change index number

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friend I am making app which has different wallpapers in a `GridView`. For example if the user clicks on wallpaper 6, the wallpaper will be displayed in `Singleimage` which I have provided here. Now what I want to achieve is a simple gesture detection for previous and next images using swipes. For example if user comes on `Singleimage` screen and taps on wallpaper 6 and then swipes to the left, the wallpaper 5 will then be displayed. If I swipe to the right the next wallpaper will be displayed.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
        class Singleimage extends StatelessWidget{
         late final String foldername;
         late final int categorynumber;
         late final int index;
         late final String categoryname;
        
         Singleimage(this.foldername, this.categorynumber, this.index, this.categoryname);
        
         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('TITLE HERE'),
              ),
              body:Container(
                color: Colors.black,
                child: PageView.builder(
                  itemCount:categorynumber,
                  itemBuilder: (context,index){
                    return  Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                         Container(
                          height: 500,
                          width: double.infinity,
                          color:Colors.black,
                          child: Image.asset('assets/images/arm/1.jpg'),
                        ), Text('1',style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white
                        ),)
        
                      ],
        
                    );
                  },
        
                ),
              ),
            );
          }
        
        
        }







import 'package:favorite_button/favorite_button.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:untitled1/Singleimage.dart';

class CategoriesDetails extends StatelessWidget {
  late String categoryname;
  late int categorynumber;
  late String foldername;
  CategoriesDetails(this.categoryname, this.categorynumber,this.foldername);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Text(categoryname),
  ),
  body:Container(
    color: Colors.black,
    child: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: categorynumber,
      gridDelegate:SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 2
      ),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
          child: Container(
            child: Column(
              children: [
             Expanded(
             child: Stack(
               alignment: Alignment.topRight,
               children: [
               Container(
                     margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:10, horizontal:6),
                     height: 200,
                     width: 200,
                     color: Colors.amber,
                     child:  GestureDetector(
                       onTap: (){
                         Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>Singleimage(foldername,categorynumber,index,categoryname)));
                       },
                       child: Image.asset(
                         'assets/images/${foldername}/${index+1}.jpg',
                         height: 100,
                         fit: BoxFit.cover,
                       ),
                     )
                 ),
                 Positioned(
                   top: 0,
                   right: 0,
                   child: IconButton(
                     onPressed: () async {},
                     color: Colors.white,
                     icon: Icon(Icons.favorite_border),


                   ),
                 )
               ],

             ),
           ),
                Text(
                '${index+1}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  color: Colors.white
                ),)

              ],

            ),
          ),
        ) ;

      },

    ),
  ),

);
  }


}
```